# setRetainInstance on Fragments doubles listView items

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

After screen rotation, the fragment is smoothly retained but the problem is, my code for generating items on my listView get called again, which makes the the previous list doubled with the same items.

What I did, I tried checking if `retainInstance` is `true` then I will return the view. Then I get the **`11-15 19:18:52.097: E/AndroidRuntime(1620): java.lang.StackOverflowError`**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(this.getRetainInstance()){

            return this.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        }else{
        this.setRetainInstance(true);

         /** CODE FOR GENERATING LISTVIEW **/

         return view;

        }
```

---

***UPDATE***

```
   if(mDrawerList.get().getCount()==0){

    /*RUN AsyncTask*/

    }
```

**AsyncTask for listview**

```
       List<Menu> items;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            /*GET FROM THE DATABASE*/
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

               if(items.size() == 0){

                /*PREPARE DATA AND PUT IT IN ARRAYLIST*/
               }
        }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                super.onPostExecute(file_url);
            /*NEW CUSTOM ADAPTER*/
            mDrawerList.get().setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: `return this.onCreateView` is infinite recursion. You simply always create the listview as if there was none. Views are not retained.

Comment: @zapl I just wanted to return view of the `retainedInstance`.

Comment: Yes, that' what I did before, but the listview items are doubled. Its like an existing list plus another list with the same items.

Comment: Check the place that adds the data. If you add it to something like `private List<Data>` than that will be retained and you are likely adding it again.

Comment: @zapl I added some updates on how I add items. I am not sure if which one is retained like the listview itself is retained and its items or the `List<Menu> items;` is the one being retained. But i have also added a checker that id the drawer is empty that where the async is execute